# WP Rest API v2 - how can I get author information from v2 - I try "_embed" this

Tags: json, wordpress, rest

I have a question for wp-json. I was research the problem. I saw the answer that someone was saying to add "_embed" parameter in my link. And I was add the parameter, but doesn't work. This is my result screenshot.

[image]

How can I get author information from WP-json v2 API?